# Finding pressure sensor specifications of portable integrity test device

Tags: device, portable

I have a [portable integrity test device (BEA Technologies – Italy)](https://www.bea-italy.com/en/download/beatest/), model Z02030300 (X-150-N.)

The pressure sensor inside is broken. I do not know the manufacturer of the sensor.

Does anyone know a clue to find the specifications?

In the pressure sensor, I can see the text “MI-CUX5/C7CFXL”, but cannot find any info.

Please check the photos.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: They did not provide technical specifications but suggested that we replace the entire board.

Comment: Part looks similar to a Honeywell sensor (see link below), though most look similar, it could be a copy. Is the P/N on a paper label, any thing under that? If you knew all the specifications a similar Honeywell part may be suitable. Any repair or replacement would likely require that the unit be re-calibrated. https://prod-edam.honeywell.com/content/dam/honeywell-edam/sps/siot/en-ca/products/sensors/pressure-sensors/board-mount-pressure-sensors/trustability-ssc-series/documents/sps-siot-trustability-ssc-series-standard-accuracy-board-mount-pressure-sensors-50099533-a-en-ciid-151134.pdf#page=25

Comment: Thank you a lot for you suggestion